# OOP/Maintainble alternatives to including pages with switch statement

Tags: php, oop, validation, url, include

I have pages in my website with URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=about  
http://example.com/index.php?page=portofolio
http://example.com/index.php?page=location
http://example.com/index.php?page=mission
http://example.com/index.php?page=contact
http://example.com/index.php?page=register
http://example.com/index.php?page=login
```

Now, the objective is to include be it a simple `about.html` page containing a simple text about the company, or a form processor file called `register.php` when `?page=register` is called.

This is how I am handling the contents.

```
$id= isset($_GET && !empty($_GET['page'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['page']) : false; 

switch($id){
  case 'about': 
    include 'about.html';
    break;

  case 'porofolio': 
    include 'portofolio.html';
    break;

  case 'contact': 
    include 'contact_form.html';
    include 'contact_process.php';
  break;

  case 'login':
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_login'])){
      echo 'You are already logged in';
    }else{
     include 'login_form.html';
     include 'login_process.php';
   }

  default: 
   die('Page not found'); 
  break;

}
```

Yes, I know It is horrible. I know trust me. That is why, I need better maintainable solution to this.

Now, if you are just curious what could be inside `process_login.php` It looks like:

```
if($_POST){
  if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
     try{
         $pdo = new PDO(...); 
         $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"); 
         if($stmt->rowCount(){
             $_SESSION['user_login'] = $_POST['username']; 
             header('location: success.php'); exit; 
          }
      } 
   }


}
```

This is just an example I quickly wrote, so there may be some typo or another thing I've left. What I am interested to know is how to better create/emulate a practice of handling the switch statements, as it does not seem to me a good oop-oriented approach for such task. I want something maintainable, extensible approach.

If you are wandering why I have only have one page `index.php`, it is because I don't want to create static pages for all the pages, as they have the same layout, making the HTML improvement easier. Instead of one day, opening 7 files to change/add a single tag, it would make sense to do it only once.

second, if you wandering why I chose to include the `about.html` page instead of simple storing the plain text in database, is because I didn't want to create a field/table/connection just for that 10 line simple text, as I would be saving some overhead performance. (Although I am sure, you may not agree on this)

So, the general question is, how to get rid of that complexity with switch statement, which makes me end up creating files like `login_process.php` instead of dealing with it, in some OOP way that I am not aware of.

Sorry for the wall of text :( and thanks in advance.

Comment: That switch is nowhere near as bad as a bunch of if/elseif statements in a row!

Comment: [Symfony2 and HTTP Fundamentals](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html) is a nice read. Or [Front Controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), in general.

Comment: @Yoshi I have read the controller pattern, do you think that concept is applicable to a non-mvc oriented design?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that you're looking for is really MVC and templating your views. Further, you're essentially creating your own router, your router is pretty simple compared to some of the complex routing schemes found in some of the major frameworks, so if you're looking to simplify further, that's going to be kinda difficult.

If you want to see how this is all done in a very OOP manner, checkout something like the Zend Framework 2, CakePHP, etc.

Comment: I really hate frameworks. They add unnecessary complexity to simple project as this one. I don't want to run 20 libraries for simple sites, plus when I create a site, I want to know where, and what is going on behind the process. but thanks for the response.

Comment: I have felt the same way more times than not. But after wrapping my head around a couple of frameworks my productivity increased tremendously. The learning curve is really the annoying part.

Comment: Yeah, but there should be some alternatives that does not support the idea of the MVC design pattern.

Comment: The design pattern's goal is to make the code modular and maintainable